# In visual Studio how to create a PDF which contains data from the database?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pdf-generation

In VS 2010, I need to pick some data from the database and want to add it to the pdf. How is it possible? Please someone elaborate.

Comment: Did you look into http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ and did you accept some answers on your previous questions?

Comment: Ya i am using itextsharp for this. I am able to get the data from the database. But not understanding how to show this data in the pdf file?